# adding commas as thousands to numerical string in batch

Tags: string, batch-file

I was wondering if there was a simplistic code to add commas as thousands separators in variables that takes into account the length of the digit. For example, if The variable equals `123576` I would want it to become `123,456`, but if the variable were equal to `1234567` then I would want it to turn into `1,234,567`.

Comment: Define simplistic? Surely that would depend upon us determining your current level of knowledge relative to our own. Anyhow, I'm going to make such a determination and say **no**.

Comment: I mean possible without creating a convoluted script

Comment: as far as how much knowledge I have, not that much but with the knowledge that I have, I have managed to create a batch file that can perform selection sort with an amount of variables that is determined by a user input. I also did the same with gnome sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ECHO Processing %num%
SET "withcommas="
:subl
IF DEFINED num SET "withcommas=%num:~-3%,%withcommas%"&SET "num=%num:~0,-3%"&GOTO subl
SET "withcommas=%withcommas:~0,-1%"
ECHO result=%withcommas%
```

Processes `num` to required format. Note : `num` will be undefined by code.